The problem of group theory and polynomials

Using the homomorphism theorem for rings, establish the isomorphism $\mathbb{C}[x]/\left ( x^2+3x \right )\simeq \mathbb{C}\oplus \mathbb{C}$, where $ \mathbb{C}\oplus \mathbb{C}=\left \{ (z_1,z_2)|z_1,z_2\in \mathbb{C} \right \}$ - ring with componentwise addition and multiplication operations

The ring of polynomials $\mathbb{C}[x]$ and the ideal generated by the polynomial $x^2 + 3x$. This ring is especially important as $R = \mathbb{C}[x]$ and ideally as $I = \left(x^2 + 3x\right)$. Then the quotient ring $R/I$ consists of equivalence classes of polynomials with respect to the ideal model $I$. Now we define the homomorphism $\phi: \mathbb{C}[x] \rightarrow \mathbb{C} \oplus \mathbb{C}$. This homomorphism will transfer the polynomial $f(x)$ to the pair $(f(0), f(-3))$. Let us check that $\phi$ $-$ is a ring homomorphism. For any two polynomials $f(x), g(x) \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ we have
$$
   \begin{aligned}
   \phi(f + g) &= \phi(f(x) + g(x)) \\
   &= \left(f(0) + g(0), f(-3) + g(-3)\right) \\
   &= (f(0), f(-3)) + (g(0), g(-3)) \\
   &= \phi(f) + \phi(g).
   \end{aligned}
$$
Thus $\phi$ preserves the operation of addition. Now let's check the conservation of multiplication
$$
   \begin{aligned}
   \phi(f \cdot g) &= \phi(f(x) \cdot g(x)) \\
   &= \phi\left(\sum_{i=0}^{m}\sum_{j=0}^{n} a_ib_jx^{i+j}\right) \\
   &= \left(\sum_{i=0}^{m}\sum_{j=0}^{n} a_ib_j \cdot 0^{i+j}, \sum_{i=0}^{m}\sum_{j=0}^{n} a_ib_j \cdot (-3)^{i+j}\right) \\
   &= (f(0)g(0), f(-3)g(-3)) \\
   &= \phi(f)\phi(g).
   \end{aligned}
$$
Thus $\phi$ preserves the multiplication operation. Let us show that $\phi$ is surjective. Let $(z_1, z_2) \in \mathbb{C} \oplus \mathbb{C}$. Consider the polynomial $f(x) = (x-z_1)(x+z_2)$. Then $\phi(f) = (f(0), f(-3)) = (z_1, z_2)$. Thus, for any pair $(z_1, z_2) \in \mathbb{C} \oplus \mathbb{C}$ there is a polynomial $f(x)$ such that $\phi(f) = (z_1, z_2) $, which means $\phi$ is surjective
Let's find the kernel $\phi$. The polynomial $f(x)$ belongs to the kernel $\phi$ if and only if $\phi(f) = (0, 0)$. This is only possible if $f(0) = 0$ and $f(-3) = 0$. This means that $f(x)$ must be divisible by $x(x+3)$ since $0$ and $-3$ are roots of the polynomial $f(x)$. Thus $\ker(\phi) = (x(x+3))$.
Am I thinking correctly and have I solved the problem?

It turns out that only one part was solved incorrectly? Everything else is correct?

From the [tag:solution-verification] tag wiki: "A question with this tag should include an explanation for why the argument presented is not convincing enough."
